# Label First and Last data points on a r Plot

Tags: r

I have seen many examples using directlabels to place labels on plot itself.  However, all the examples only label the lines or points with the name of the series, i.e pretty much like legend.

Is it possible to label the first and last data points with the values of the points?  E.g.

```
   1-Jan 2-Jan ... 31-Jan
A   10     3   ...    7
B    8    11   ...   20
```

If the above data is plotted as line charts, is it possible to place a label on the left of the 2 lines as 10 and 8, and likewise label the right most points as 7 and 20?

*Update*: Thanks for the comments.  Yes, I am using ggplot.  I attach a mock-up below just to illustrate my requirement:

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Can expand what you intend to use for plotting? ggplot? 

If I understand you correctly want to have the data point values displayed next to each data point. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

with `ggplot2` you can pass the desired subset which you want to be labled in to `data`

add the below to your `ggplot`

```
p + geom_point() + geom_text(data="subset condition"), .....)
```